# Printf Format Issue. Won't Align

Tags: java, printf

I've looked into a bunch of questions on here about my problem, and even on Java, but I have not been able to figure it out. Here is my code

```
System.out.printf(
    "%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s\n",
    "Record #",
    "Inventory",
    "Size", "Color", "Cost", "Markup", "Sale Price", "QTY", "SKU #");

    for (int x = 0; x < StoreInventory.inventory.length; ++x) {
        System.out.printf(
           "%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s\n", x + 1,
            StoreInventory.inventory[x][0],
            StoreInventory.inventory[x][1],
            StoreInventory.inventory[x][2],
            StoreInventory.buyPrice[x],
            StoreInventory.markUp[x],
            StoreInventory.storeSalePrice[x],
            StoreInventory.quantity[x],
            StoreInventory.skuNumber[x]);
}
```

The Output Is:

```
Record #             Inventory            Size                           Color                Cost                 Markup               Sale Price           QTY                  SKU #               
1                    SHORTS               XL                   BLACK                5.0                  10.0                 50.0                 10                   SL-1234AE
```

All the fields are user input.
What do I need to change to align the output regardless of the size of the input?

Comment: your problem is not in the code; the code should function correctly.

Comment: what could it be? im truthfully lost.

Comment: It is possible that you have something like a tab in the "Color" string.  Beyond that, I'm not sure.  Try writing a simple test that outputs the first 3 headers and the first three values.  assuming that works, add Color and repeat.

Comment: All the variables are user input

Comment: The labels appear to be hard coded and it appears that the labels are demonstrating the alignment issue.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, should I turn them into variables?

Comment: I made a new string for all the labels and implemented it into the format yet it still has the bad output. Any idea why?